# Communication between c# and MySql solution required

Tags: c#, .net, desktop-application

I am developing Desktop application using c#.net and MySql. Is there any solution to communicate with MySql with out any extra dll file. as I am using MySql.Data.dll and I have to put that file with my exe file which is not feasible solution.

Comment: is there a specific reason why you do not want to put the dll file with your exe ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively you could try to merge the MySql.Data.dll into your exe using for example [one of the tools discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025843/merging-dlls-into-a-single-exe-with-wpf). Or, if your app doesn't use the database heavily, you could create some kind of central service application that your app talks to (through web services, perhaps) and that in turn handles the database querying (using MySql.Data.dll).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like an amazingly inefficient use of your time, but if distributing a MySql.Data.dll is really forbidden you could always download the source code and try to bundle it within your app.
https://launchpad.net/connectornet