# Serious trouble with ILMerge and .NET 4.0

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-4.0, ilmerge

For the life of me, I can't seem to get my .NET 4 application merging properly with ILMerge. Even after setting /targetplatform, /lib, /ndebug *and* adding a custom ILMerge.exe.config file the output file doesn't work properly (it doesn't seem to be able to "find" the merged libraries).

I've tried [this](http://mint.litemedia.se/2010/07/06/merge-assemblies-with-ilmerge/) and [this](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx) to no avail. I can't even get it to build unless I use the config file, but when I do it doesn't work. Without the config file, I consistently get the error message "**Unresolved assembly reference not allowed: PresentationFramework**".

Here is the current state of my ILMerge command being used as a post build event:

```
ilmerge.exe /out:C:\Users\Logan\Development\Projects\OrangeNote\OrangeNote\bin\Release\OrangeNote.exe 
  /ndebug /targetplatform:v4,C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 
  /lib:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319" 
  /lib:"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies" 
  "C:\Users\Logan\Development\Projects\OrangeNote\OrangeNote\obj\Release\OrangeNote.exe" 
  "C:\Users\Logan\Development\Projects\OrangeNote\OrangeNote\..\..\..\Libraries\Lucene.Net\src\Lucene.Net\bin\Release\Lucene.Net.dll" 
  "C:\Users\Logan\Development\Projects\OrangeNote\OrangeNote\..\..\..\Libraries\Ookii.Dialogs\src\Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf\bin\Release\Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf.dll" 
  "C:\Users\Logan\Development\Projects\OrangeNote\OrangeNote\..\..\..\Libraries\SharpZipLib\bin\ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll" 
  "C:\Users\Logan\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\HumanInterfaceProject\HumanInterfaceProject\bin\Release\HipLib.dll"
```

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong??

Comment: I resolve it simply by adding: /lib:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\WPF"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One suggestion I have seen used to combine .dlls in WPF is to simply add the dll as an embedded resource the the project and then programatically load the dll into the assembly.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, args) => {

   String resourceName = "AssemblyLoadingAndReflection." +

      new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name + ".dll";

   using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName)) {

      Byte[] assemblyData = new Byte[stream.Length];

      stream.Read(assemblyData, 0, assemblyData.Length);

      return Assembly.Load(assemblyData);

   }

};
```

see:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx

Comment: This is great, thanks! Even Mike Barnett (the author of ILMerge) considers this to be a solution, so it's good enough for me. :)

Comment: Note that this makes it impossible to Ngen the dll files.

Comment: This doesn't work for class libraries: scroll down to see Jeffrey Ritcher's comment about this in the link in the answer, the comment is dated 28 Jul 2010 3:14 PM.

Comment: If you don't want to manually embed all your DLLs manually you can have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4995039/2576706

Answer (score 8):

You could try Costura.

https://github.com/Fody/Costura#how-it-works

It basically takes Jeffrey Richters appraoch

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx

But does it in a way that you dont need to write any code. ie you dont need to write the "AssemblyResolve" method

Comment: This seems to have a broken link. But Costura now a NuGet Package as an add-on to Fody. http://www.nuget.org/packages/Costura.Fody/

Answer (score 7):

I emailed Mike Barnett, the author of ILMerge and he explained it's not designed to work with WPF apps at all, unfortunately, and was surprised when I told him that I had it working with my WPF 3.5 app. Since it's not really supported, I'll just write this off for now and wait for another alternative to present itself.

As a side note, I did try out .NET Reactor from [Eziriz](http://www.eziriz.com/), and it actually worked great, but costs $180 which for a hobby project I'm not really willing to spend just yet. But that's a whole lot cheaper than the other commercial alternative from Red Gate and so thought I'd mention it.

**Update:** Mike Barnett now considers the accepted answer to this question as the best solution. According to him, if he'd known it was possible, he never would have written ILMerge in the first place.

Comment: As a commercial user of .NET Reactor, I have to mention that I always failed to merge assemblies. It seemed to have merged successfully, but when you run the merged application, you will meet strange activities.

Comment: It seemed to work great when I stuck *just* to embedding (not merging), and no fancy security stuff at all. I did a runthrough of my program and everything seemed intact.

Answer (score 6):

While it is true that ILMerge does not update WPF resource strings, it *can* be used to merge assemblies with WPF references by passing the reference assembly directory instead of the runtime directory to `/targetplatform`, as such: `/targetplatform:v4,"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client"` (for the .NET 4.0 client profile).

I use this to merge in Rx's System.Reactive.dll, which has a reference to `Dispatcher`, but doesn't have any actual WPF resources.

Answer (score 3):

I noticed that one your your assemblies is called "dialogs.wpf". Currently ILMerge does not correctly merge assemblies with WPF resources in them.

There isn't much info around on this, but [this forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/1ba71aba-9ab2-4d66-8722-b94eca29d0b4) mentions a possible solution, and there are several possibilities mentioned on [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025843/merging-dlls-into-a-single-exe-with-wpf), but the highest voted suggestion is just to buy a commercial alternative - I don't know if that is a possibility for you.

There is a [discussion here](http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/863302-problem-merging-assemblies-using-ilmerge) that explains why it doesn't work, and there is a suggestion [here that changing the resource reference in the xaml may help solve the problem](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxbcl/thread/013811c2-63a8-474d-9bdf-f2ab79f28099).

Comment: I don't believe there are actually any WPF resources in that assembly, but I'm not completely sure (will check when I get home). My main executable certainly does, but that doesn't appear to be the problem. Still I will look into this further. Thanks for the reply.