# How to merge assemblies of a WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, ilmerge

I tried to use ILMerge on my WPF-based project (VS2010, Net4.0) but I couldn't make the merged executable to run. So I created two very simply projects

- just a console application which prints out hello world
- wpf application which shows window with hello world label

After compiling each project I get single executable file (so merging, does not really merge anything, it is just for test). Each executable works of course.

Then I "merge" each executable this way:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft\ILMerge\ilmerge" 
    /targetplatform:v4,c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 
    /lib:c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\wpf 
    /out:Merged.exe MyApplication.exe
```

(I made the call multiline just for SO readability). Ok, now console application is merged and runs as fine as before, the wpf application is merged without any errors but I cannot run it. I mean, I type

```
Merged.exe
```

Taskbar blinks, but nothing shows up -- no window, no error, nothing.

So how should I merge WPF app?

Comment: You can treat assemblies as ressources, see my answer [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025843/merging-dlls-into-a-single-exe-with-wpf/7025702#7025702

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merging dlls into a single .exe with wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025843/merging-dlls-into-a-single-exe-with-wpf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I know (and have experienced) ilmerge does not work correctly with WPF assemblies that have xaml resources embedded.

[See this question for some possible solutions/alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025843/merging-dlls-into-a-single-exe-with-wpf)

Comment: Thank you, it seems merging assemblies comes at cost of nearly $1000 :-(

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit prohibitive - not sure can justify the cost myself to the company. What I ended up doing was merging all the assemblies except the WPF exe one

Comment: I have to admit though that the general attitude towards solving problems (SmartAssembly) is outstanding. However 10% of the price for me would be a stretch. I have definitive word from Mike Barnett (author of ILMerge) -- it is not capable of merging WPF apps. Period. So I probably end up with your solution.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to embedded all assemblies into one exe.

There is an amazing NuGet package called [Costura.Fody](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Costura.Fody/). Merging assemblies could not be easier!

If you need to merge Resource DLLs, you are in luck! There is another NuGet that extends Costura.Fody called [Resource.Embedder](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Resource.Embedder/)!