# Is there any free ilmerge like tool out there which can merge wpf assemblies?

Tags: .net, wpf, ilmerge, fody-costura

I'm looking for a free tool to merge all of my wpf application's assemblies into a single assembly. Usually, I use ILMerge, but unfortunately, it does not support merging WPF assemblies. Are there any tools out there which can achieve that?

A commercial tool is not an option for me because the application is an open source project.

Best Regards,
Oliver Hanappi

Comment: Are you getting an error when trying to merge WPF assemblies? Those should still be .Net assemblies, which should make them usable to ILMerge.

Comment: @Hugo ILMerge doesn't know about BAML, so the resources are broken when you merge stuff.

Comment: Ah, good to know, thanks for the clarification Paul. There's my mandatory one new thing to learn for today!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two relevant solutions:

1. Implement your assembly resolution handling at runtime so ilmerge'd WPF assemblies do work:
   http://blog.mahop.net/post/Merge-WPF-Assemblies.aspx
2. Use a product that supports it out of the box (Commercial, so not an option in the case below):
   [Merging dlls into a single .exe with wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025843/merging-dlls-into-a-single-exe-with-wpf)

Answer (score 7):

Costura can do this.

It embeds references as resources in the target assembly. Then at run time intercepts assembly  load events and serves up the resource.

https://github.com/Fody/Costura