# Build a Portable Visual Studio 2010 Application

Tags: c#

How do you compile and export a finished C# program in Visual Studio in a single executable?

Comment: do you mean without relying on the .net redistributable to be installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As soon as you press the compile button an executable file is created inside the bin/debug-folder of where you save your project. Unless you've created a class-library the program is just that one .exe file. For every class-library you create there will be a .dll file so as long as you don't use class-libraries you'll be fine.

Comment: Except not using class-libraries results in horribly unmaintainable monster assemblies, and hakes it harder to enforce single responsibility.  A better solution is to allow development to proceed taking full advantage of different libraries and merge them afterwards.

Comment: But if you're ending up with one assembly then there is no single responsibility for every class-library you use in your project, because you still have to recompile the whole project into one monster assembly as you call it. Though I agree for your own purposes that it's more maintainable.

Comment: But you do the merge after development - for all intents and purposes you maintain a nicely separated assembly structure.  Merging them becomes a deployment concern not a development concern.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant with "Though I agree for your own purposes that it's more maintainable". I agree with your opinions, I was just stating that when assembled there is no more single responsibility e.g. you can't just recompile one of the .dll's.

Answer (score 3):

You can merge libraries into your exe using a variety of tools.

See [Merging dlls into a single .exe with wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025843/merging-dlls-into-a-single-exe-with-wpf) for an example.