# How to build a portable program by visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv

I am using visual studio 2010 under Win7-64bit to build an application with openCV. I finished development and build the release version without error. I also successfully run the program in debug mode. I then move the `.exe` file to other directory in the same computer. I run it in `cmd.exe` and I got error `warning: Error opening file <../../modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_implhpp:537>`

I guess there are some dependence with some libraries of openCV but I don't how to solve it. My final task is that I can use that `.exe` in another computer under Win7 directly. How to do it?

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301207/build-a-portable-visual-studio-2010-application). But I don't have `.dll` file built, so what should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building an OpenCV app with shared libs (DLLs) require the DLLs to be available (same folder or in lookup path) to the `exe` when it is run.

If you are using static linking then you don't need any of the OpenCV DLLs to be reachable. *However*, due to licensing issues, ffmpeg is linked dynamically *even* when the rest of the libs are linked statically, and thus, you need to have the ffmpeg DLL available for the `exe`. It is called something like `opencv_ffmpeg*.dll`.

Note that this is only needed if you are using `highgui` related functionality.

Comment: Thank you, I found the problem.