# Using .NetZ and WPF causes System.IO.IOException

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

My aim is to be able to use any packer for C# applications and libraries (preferring WPF) via command line or full build-in at Visual Studio.

I came accross .NetZ (http://madebits.com/netz/) that is pretty neat and worked pretty well until I tested it with a WPF application:

```
PackageExample.Program -> C:\Users\[username]\Documents\Visual Studio 
2012\Projects\PackageExample\PackageExample.Program\bin\Debug\PackageExample.Program.exe
COMMAND: packcompress\netz-bin-40\netz.exe -o PackageExample.Program\bin\Debug\Packed -pl 
anycpu -s -z PackageExample.Program\bin\Debug\PackageExample.Program.exe 
"PackageExample.Program\bin\Debug\*.dll" -d:@ -v
 __________________________________________ 
|                                          |
| .NETZ - .NET Executables Compressor      |
| Copyright (C) 2004-2013 Vasian Cepa      |
| [v0.4.8]  http://madebits.com            |
|__________________________________________|

PE subsystem    : GUI
.NET Runtime    : 4.0.30319.18052
Output directory: C:\Users\[username]\Documents\Visual Studio 
2012\Projects\PackageExample\PackageExample.Program\bin\Debug\Packed
     RID: zip.dll
Added           : C:\Users\[username]\Documents\Visual Studio 
2012\Projects\PackageExample\packcompress\netz-bin-40\zip.dll [65536 byte(s) ~ 64KB]
Processing      : 3 file(s)

 1|  C:\Users\[username]\Documents\Visual Studio 
2012\Projects\PackageExample\PackageExample.Program\bin\Debug\PackageExample.Program.exe
     [255488 byte(s) ~ 249KB] -> [130850 byte(s) ~ 127KB] - 49%
     RID: A6C24BF5-3690-4982-887E-11E1B159B249
 2|  C:\Users\[username]\Documents\Visual Studio 
2012\Projects\PackageExample\PackageExample.Program\bin\Debug\PackageExample.Lib1.dll
     [4096 byte(s) ~ 4KB] -> [1577 byte(s) ~ 1KB] - 62%
     RID: PackageExample.Lib1!2!1Version=1.0.0.0!2!1!4=neutral!2!1PublicKeyToken=null
 3|  C:\Users\[username]\Documents\Visual Studio 
2012\Projects\PackageExample\PackageExample.Program\bin\Debug\PackageExample.Lib2.dll
     [4608 byte(s) ~ 4KB] -> [1617 byte(s) ~ 1KB] - 65%
     RID: PackageExample.Lib2!2!1Version=1.0.0.0!2!1!4=neutral!2!1PublicKeyToken=null

Done [00:00:00.300]
```

The packed app throws this: http://i.imagebanana.com/img/251ygj82/Unbenannt.PNG
(The ressource mainwindow.xaml cannot be found.)

The problem seems to be the xaml .NetZ confuses, but I found some people who got it working on the internet, but I do not get any problem solution.

Are you able to help me in this case?

Additional information: It might be interesting to mention I even tried this with the .NET 2.0 .NetZ build on a .NET 3.5 WPF application.

Answer (score 1):

I also had problems using NetZ to compress an WPF 4.0 exe and DLLs into a single exe.
My app.xml.cs would start to run, but then an UnhandledException of type NotImplementedException would be thrown:
   Baml2006SchemaContext.ResolveBamlType ...

To troubleshoot this, I ran fuslogvw.exe to see assembly binding errors, and discovered that GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Wpf4.dll was failing to load from the Netz-packed assembly.
I then switched to NetZ.exe compiled from source and tried again.
After repeated experimentation, I see that if I recompile and NetZ-pack the app, it sometimes starts working. Recompile again the main app again, and NetZ produces a failing app.
In other words, something is intermittent.
Sorry for the not-so good news - either try another packing scheme, or try NetZ repeatedly on many builds, until you find a working one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I decided to not use any after-build solution, finally. It will not pack my files, just merge the .NET components, and it works with WPF, too. The article is quite long. If you are still searching for solution, too, check this: http://forum.ragezone.com/f578/net-merging-net-components-961798/