# wpftoolkit chartin, namespace referencing in XAML

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit

I am using the basic WPFToolkit - I have both DLL's embedded in my EXE. I followed this tutorial:http://www.digitallycreated.net/Blog/61/combining-multiple-assemblies-into-a-single-exe-for-a-wpf-application

Everything is working with the DLL not embedded. When embedded, while I can compile with no error, I get a parsing error pointing at the XAML referencing of the wpftoolkit dll.

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:chartingToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit" x:Class="Swiftech_Imperium.MainWindow"
```

both DLL's are set to embedded resources, and both references are set to do not copy.

If I enable copy local for the system.windows.controls.datavisualization.toolkit.dll it works, but then I need the DLL at the root of the exe (I shouldn't need that since it's already embedded in the EXE - and I can't do this for this specific project..)

any idea what's wrong here?

thanks

Comment: thanks, can I do that at AssemblyResolve level?

Answer (score 0):

Just because the .DLL reference is set to `Embedded Resource` doesn't mean the libraries will get resolved/loaded at runtime.  You need to manually do that.  I'm not sure if WPFToolKit can successfully do that, but to test it, you will want to to follow the answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4995039/1144624).