# Create a standalone exe file in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, wpf, deployment, visual-studio-2019, publish

I would like to create an exe file from my WPF project which can work without other project files and which can be ran on different computers.
Currently, I'm using the Publish function in Build > Publish ProjectName, with these options:

Profile name: FolderProfile 
Delete existing files: false 
Configuration: Release | Any Cpu 
Target framework: net5.0-windows 
Deployment mode: Framework-dependent 
Target runtime: Portable 
Target Location: \bin\Release\net5.0-windows\publish\

Even if successfully published, I found various files in the target location and when I copied the exe in a different folder, externally to the project folder, it didn't work and no window appeared.

Any suggestion? Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merging dlls into a single .exe with wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025843/merging-dlls-into-a-single-exe-with-wpf)

Comment: There's no  equivalent to the `--self-contained` CLI option in VS? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish

Comment: Currently, I'm using a command string in the _Developer PowerShell_ (right click on the solution name in the _Solution Explorer_ -> _Open in terminal_). The string command is 
`dotnet publish -c release --self-contained -r win-x64 -p:PublishSingleFile=true`. I get this error:
_C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.302\NuGet.targets(131,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json_

My PC is not connected, so problably this is why i get the error. Is there any other method to publish a single .exe file without the need of the internet connection?

Answer (score 5):

You could try the following steps:

1. Right-click on the project and select Publish.
2. Choose the location you want to deploy, as an example, I choose the folder, and then next->finish.
   [image]
3. Click Edit, set Deployment Mode to Self-contained, expand File publish options, and select Produce single file.
   [image]