# Cannot run any batch file unless ran as administrator

Tags: batch-file, cmd, associations, progid

When I double any batch file (even something as simple as "echo test") in the explorer or from anywhere else (windows 10 ONLY in my user account). I get this error message:

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

If I right click the batch file and run it as an admin, it will run with no problem. Opening a cmd.exe and running the file with ./test.bat will also works. It seem it's a problem with the file associations?

If I run assoc to get the ProgId, the entry with .bat is the following:

> .bat=batfile

If I check the executable associated with the batfile ProgId (ftype | find "batfile), I get this:

> batfile="%1" %*

I've tried changing the executable associated with the batfile ProgId to

```
cmd.exe /c "%1" %*
```

in the registry (*HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\open\command*) and it does seem to work, but is it really right answer to this?

I have also used procmon to see the difference with the fix and without it.

**With cmd.exe as progId**

```
Event Path: *C:\Users\User\test.bat*\
Process Path: *C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe*\
Process Command: *"cmd.exe" /c "C:\Users\User\test.bat*\
```

**Without it (default)**

```
Event Path: *C:\Windows\System32\"C:\Users\User\test.bat"*\
Process Path: *C:\WINDOWS\system32\svchost.exe*\
Process Command: *C:\WINDOWS\system32\svchost.exe -k netsvcs -p -s Appinfo*
```

Comment: It sounds like your script was saved with a coding other than ANSI and you need to resave it. My settings are also `.bat=batfile` and `batfile="%1" %*` and scripts work correctly for me.

Comment: @SomethingDark The script was saved in UTF-8. The problem does not lie in any of the scripts I'm trying to run. This is happening on all batch files in my, the ones created by me or the ones that came with programs in my PC.

Comment: Perhaps it is a problem with the `PATH` environment variable. Carefully review all the values in such a variable.

Answer (score -2):

That depends if your bat script need to be share with any end-user for deployment purpose or if it will deploy as task job.
Anyway, reliable option to fix privilege issue is to transform the .bat file into portable .exe file.
This link can be used how to create .exe via visual basic.  [Create a standalone exe file in Visual Studio 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69016697/create-a-standalone-exe-file-in-visual-studio-2019)

Comment: Not only is that completely irrelevant to the question, turning the script into an exe file just makes it a self-extracting archive that keeps it as a script but runs it from `%TEMP%`.

Comment: **1.** Your answer is not related to the problem posted. **2.** Converting a .bat file to an .exe is _never_ good advice; It has been repeatedly proven to cause several problems. **3.** The link posted has nothing to do with converting a .bat file to an .exe.