# Compile to stand alone exe for C# app in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, console-application

Similar to this question
[Compile to a stand-alone executable (.exe) in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035083/compile-to-a-stand-alone-executable-exe-in-visual-studio)

But nothing there works for me.

I've written an app that is very simple in C#.  I want this to compile to a stand alone exe file, but I can't seem to find the proper settings to do this.  Everything compiles into a publish folder and there is only the setup/install files.

Thanks!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You just compile it. In the bin\Release (or bin\Debug) folder, the .exe will be in there.

If you're asking how to make an executable which does not rely on the .NET framework at all, then that's a lot harder and you'll need to purchase something like [RemoteSoft's Salamader](http://www.remotesoft.com/linker/intro.html). In general, it's not really worth the bother: Windows Vista comes with .NET framework 2.0 pre-installed already so if you're worried about that, you can just target the 2.0 framework (then only XP users would have to install the framework).

Comment: Nothing shows up in the bin/Release folder though. (and I have set the project to Release)

No, I am expecting to package the framework.

Comment: This worked for me for a C# program code I downloaded from Github.  Now I have just the executable to run the program.

Answer (score 3):

I am using visual studio 2010 to make a program on [SMSC Server](http://blog.ektel.com.np/2012/01/sms-messages-between-esme-server-and-smsc-server/). What you have to do is go to build-->publish. you will be asked be asked to few simple things and the location where you want to store your application, browse the location where you want to put it.

I hope this is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you selected Console Application?  I'm running VS 2010 and with the vanilla settings a C# console app builds to \bin\debug.  Try to create a new Console Application project, with the language set to C#.  Build the project, and go to Project/[Console Application 1]Properties.  In the Build tab, what is the Output path?  It should default to bin\debug, unless you have some restricted settings on your workstation,etc. Also review the build output window and see if any errors are being thrown - in which case nothing will be built to the output folder, of course...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the files from debug folder,however if you look at app debug informations with some inspection software,you can clearly see "Symbols File Name" which can reveals not wanted informations in path to the original exe file.

Answer (score 0):

Press the start button in visual studio.  Then go to the location where your solution is stored and open the folder of your main project then the bin folder.  If your application was running in debug mode then go to the debug folder.  If running in release mode then go to the release folder.  You should find your exe there.

Answer (score -1):

> You can get single file EXE after build the console application

your Application folder - > bin folder -> there will have lot of files
there is need 2 files must and other referenced dlls

```
1. IMG_PDF_CONVERSION [this is my application name, take your application name]
2. IMG_PDF_CONVERSION.exe [this is supporting configure file]
3. your refered dll's
```

then you can move that 3(exe, configure file, refered dll's) dll to any folder that's it

if you click on 1st IMG_PDF_CONVERSION  it will execute the application cool way

any calcification please ask your queries.

Comment: Compile to a standalone executable to have a single file in the bin/debug or bin/release folder.