# How to build a whole .NET Framework application as a single .exe file?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have developed some software with no database. I want to create a stand-alone .exe of my .NET Framework project so I can give only the .exe file to users to use the software.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to create a stand-alone .exe of my project in .Net.

Does anybody have guidance for this problem?

Comment: See [Compile to stand alone exe for C# app in Visual Studio 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962816/compile-to-stand-alone-exe-for-c-app-in-visual-studio-2010)

Answer (score 28):

Something like [ILMerge](https://github.com/dotnet/ILMerge) perhaps?

There's even a [GUI](https://bitbucket.org/wvd-vegt/ilmergegui/src/master/)

Note: I haven't actually tried either of them.

Answer (score 9):

There is the Costura.Fody add on, and this compiles everything into a single exe that doesn't require installation. It can be installed via [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Costura.Fody/), however the latest version of nuget will prevent the FodyWeavers.xml file from being created, so this needs to be done manually.

Comment: latesst version as of this post: Fody: Could not find a FodyWeavers.xml file at the project level (Z:\xCode\c.sharp\[ProjectFolder]). A default file has been created. Please review the file and add it to your project.

Answer (score 2):

Found the perfect [answer](http://adamthetech.com/2011/06/embed-dll-files-within-an-exe-c-sharp-winforms/) finally

Going to post the whole page without a picture because the page is so old I'm afraid it will be deleted.

For me, I didn't bother making the references "do not copy". Also, I completely skipped stepped 4 since I couldn't add them. I wonder if it has to do with it already being added by Nuget Manager.

In the end, I could just pluck out the exe file and run it anywhere from my HDD.

Copied from the link above:

> A while back I was working on a small C# WinForms application in
> Visual Studio 2008. For the sake of simplifying the deployment process
> of the application, having all of its components bundled up into one
> exe file would make it much easier to manage. But–documentation and
> tutorials on embedding dll files within an exe file were outdated,
> incomplete, or simply didn’t work.
>
> The best example out of the lot was an excerpt from a book, posted on
> an MSDN blog by its author. Unfortunately, it didn’t work as presented
> and didn’t include clear instructions on how or where to implement it.
> However, it still offered a very good starting point. After some
> research, trial, and error, and with the help of the Visual Studio
> debugger, here’s the solution.
>
> Note: This method allows you to place dll files into any subfolder or
> series of subfolders within your project without needing to change any
> code after the fact. If you wish to forgo the use of a subfolder
> (placing the dll files in the project root), or use a hard-coded path
> to your subfolder(s) containing the dll files instead, there are
> alternative methods which would be more appropriate, but won’t be
> covered here.
>
> 1. The dll files themselves need to be embedded in the Visual Studio
>    project, rather than just referenced. In your project, create a folder
>    in the project’s root to store the dll files (right-click on the
>    project name > add > new folder). I named mine “lib”.
> 2. Copy and paste your dll (and any accompanying support or definition
>    files) into the lib folder. For purposes of this tutorial, the example
>    dll used will be Cassia.
> 3. Next, include the dll as a project resource. Right-click on the
>    project name > properties (or Project menu > yourprojectname
>    Properties). Go to the “Resources” tab.
>
> Select “Files”, as shown here:
>
> Click “Add Resource”, change the file type to “all files”, and
> navigate to the “lib” file where your dll is located. Select it and
> click “Open”.
>
> The dll file should now be included as a project resource:
>
> 4. Add a reference to the dll file in the project. In the Solution
>    Explorer pane, right-click on “References” > Add Reference (Or,
>    Project menu > Add Reference). Click the Browse tab, navigate to the
>    lib folder where the dll is located, select the dll file, and click
>    “Ok”. A reference to your dll will then appear under the references
>    folder in your project.
> 5. By default, compiled files and project references are copied to the
>    bin folder when the project is built. This will need to be prevented.
>    Under the “References” folder, select the reference to your dll file.
>    In the properties pane (or right-click > properties), look for the
>    attribute named “Copy to output directory”, and set the value to
>    false.
>
> Next, select the dll file under the “lib” folder. In the properties
> pane, look for the attribute “copy to output directory” and set the
> value to “Do not copy”.
>
> Also look for the attribute “Build Action” and set the value to
> “Embedded Resource”. This indicates how the file will be treated and
> accessed when the project is built.
>
> Lastly, exclude extraneous files accompanying the dll file, such as
> help files and XML definitions files–they are not needed in the
> project when it is built. Right-click on the file (such as the XML
> definitions file) and click “Exclude From Project”. Now it will not be
> copied to the bin folder when the project is built.
>
> 6. In the code view  for your executing WinForm, include the namespace
>    System.Reflections. This is important for some of the code responsible
>    for loading your embedded dll file(s).
> 7. In the code view for your executing WinForm, this code should be
>    placed in the constructor method (usually named the same as the form).
>    It needs to appear before the InitializeComponent() method: ```
>    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, args) => {
>    string resourceName = new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name + ".dll";
>    string resource = Array.Find(this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames(), element
>    => element.EndsWith(resourceName));
>
>    using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resource))
>    {
>    Byte[] assemblyData = new Byte[stream.Length];
>    stream.Read(assemblyData, 0, assemblyData.Length);
>    return Assembly.Load(assemblyData);
>    } }; ```
>
> Upon launching the exe, this code is responsible for detecting what
> dll files are needed and are being referenced, and load them from
> their embedded location.
>
> 8. In the code view for your executing WinForms application, you can
>    now include the dll file’s namespace(s).
> 9. In order to test everything, you will need to implement code from
>    the dll file’s namespace(s), so that the AssemblyResolve event is
>    triggered. However, if you include code from the dll’s namespace(s)
>    within the constructor, Application.Run() will throw a “file not
>    found” error for your dll file when the WinForms application is built
>    and executed.
>
> To correct this, you will need to place any code using the dll file
> namespace(s) in another method outside of constructor method. This is
> because the event handler for the assembler cannot be located within
> the same method that is calling it. It’s simple enough to do, but it’s
> just one caveat to be aware of.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried out:

- ILMerge
- Costura.Fody
- adding the files to resources and compile a new exe that will launch the original exe with dlls.

They all worked, but they were all **flagged by Windows Defender as malware** when I tried to copy them to another PC (2021-06-17). A quick scan on virustotal confirmed that this also affects other anti virus solutions. It seems that changing the way DLLs are loaded triggers anti virus heuristic.

I then tried to use a self extracting archive to simply unpack the program on launch and start the program with the DLLs from a temp directory. I've tried out 7z and Winrar with various different settings. The only reliable combination I've found is:

- Use WinRar v6.02 (the current version at the time of writing, other versions might work too)
- Keep the extracting dialogs enabled (hiding them will increase false positives)
- Use 64bit zip compression (using 32bit zip or rar will also increase false positives)

This gives me an exe file I can double click on to launch the program with the caveat that it will not run on 32bit and that the extraction dialog will show up for a brief second on launch.

That way I achieved a detection rate of 0/66 on virustotal.com: https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file-analysis/MDMxZmI3OWZiYTU3MTU1YWIxYmFmYTM0MjM4ZmE1MmE6MTYyMzkzMjY4OA==/detection

Obviously this might change in the future, so the more reliable way might be to simple distribute your exe together with the dlls as a zipped directory or to use an installer.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: And just my client called me that he cannot execute the file because his computer is 32bit. Lesson learned just use a straightforward zip file. Or an installer. All other methods are not reliable. Sucks tough, I feel Windows should provide a simple way to distribute apps as a bundle and support 1 click run.

Answer (score -3):

A .exe is automatically created when you build your project in Visual Studio.
It can be found in /bin/debug or /bin/Release folder in your project. However, you should provide the whole Debug or Release folder to your end user, if that folder contains other files besides your .exe.

PS: It is recommended that you provide only the "release" version of your .exe, instead of the "debug".

Comment: Yes . bt i don't want 2 provide any files. with. .EXE . i just want 2 provide .EXE file to end user .. that is my actual aim.

Answer (score -3):

Others have addressed the .exe question, so on a general development point not you might want to review your code and identify functions/classes that you can re-use in future developments.

You can then extract these into a separate .DLL and still provide your users with the software but development of the next application will be a bit easier and any improvements to the functions can be easily adopted in both applications...

Answer (score -3):

Create a Setup Project (look up in msdn), package your project output files within the installer. Visual studio creates an installer and bootstrapped exe file, you can use either the exe or the msi file to run your application.

Comment: yes its either .msi or .exe .. hey.. bt i don't want 2 install the .exe file.. just click on .exe file it should run ..

Comment: Like someone else mentioned in the post, you can find exe in bin/release or debug but you have to give the entire folder to your client. Easier way is the setup project exe, configure it to do nothing but just execute. Also, you can try creating a batch file executable to run the .exe file located in your bin/debug or release.

Comment: yeah bt how to create 1 .exe file . without giving all files to client.. that is my actual prb ?

Comment: And .net framework is already installed on end users side. so no worries.

Answer (score -3):

When you run your project in Visual Studio an exe of the application is created in the debug folder you can give that exe to your friends to test your application. Otherwise create a setup project in your application in the visual studio. Help is available on MSDN about setup project. The setup project will create a setup of your application like other softwares available in the market, and you can give that setup to your friends to use it.

Answer (score -3):

The .Net project when compiled gives a exe file on the Debug/release paths as set in the properties of the application. 
I think you are asking for the self extracting application setup exe file to give it to the users to use the software without giving any relevant source code or project files. 
To try packaging you can probably use application packagers available for free, try [innosetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) or Nsis and you can package it into a setup file. I use Innosetup and its easy.