# How to deploy your c# solution into single .exe file

Tags: c#, deployment, executable

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Compile to stand alone exe for C# app in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962816/compile-to-stand-alone-exe-for-c-app-in-visual-studio-2010)
>   [.Net whole application as a single .exe file ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261942/net-whole-application-as-a-single-exe-file)

Heey Guys,

so i have a C# Solution that connects to Database and i want to deploy this solution into a single .Exe file. like NotePad , in a way that makes me able to send the exe file and then double click it and it starts running ..

how can i do something like that ??

Comment: I checked that one, and it doesn't mention ILMerge (the alleged dup is asking about how to get the .exe, not about merging them into one file).  I think this question needs to stand.

Comment: @Kirk Woll well, it was between that one or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261942/net-whole-application-as-a-single-exe-file  this one (which does mention ILMerge) when I was voting, I think it's still a dupe

Comment: @Daniel, agreed.  I just didn't think it was a dup of that *specific* one. :)  Voted to close.

Comment: any concerns about the .NET framework being required?

Answer (score 5):

I think [ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=22914587-b4ad-4eae-87cf-b14ae6a939b0&displaylang=en) is what you want.  However, reflection can ruin its day.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, ILMerge is great if you aren't using reflection.  It merges a set of assemblies into a given primary assembly.

Answer (score 0):

I use [DeepSea obfuscator](http://deepseaobfuscator.com) (commercial product) to obfuscate and merge the output assemblies from several projects into a single assembly (.exe or .dll).