# StandAlone c# application

Tags: c#, .net

Sorry for the begginers question, but i want to get a firm answer.

I want to create and distribute a software(winform standalone pc app).

Now i want all the dependencies to be included in an installer, including .net.

From what is see in similar posts they say it is not possible, is it so?

[Compile to stand alone exe for C# app in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962816/compile-to-stand-alone-exe-for-c-sharp-app-in-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: Do you want a single exe-file that contains everything or an installer that installs the app on a computer?

Comment: create installer, yep Olaf i tried creating an installer and it still didnt work. but generaly an installer can have .net in it?

Comment: Installers can include .Net and all other libraries you need.

Comment: [Using Mono to avoid depending on the .NET Framework on Windows](http://blog.shilbert.com/2012/06/using-mono-to-avoid-depending-on-net-framework/) (slightly dated tutorial)

Comment: But when i add the .net to the installer, the app size gets to 50mb, thats seems not logical to me, isnt there another way? or is every project the uses .net should be at least 50mb? dosnt seem right

Comment: The days when it still made sense to have an installer deploy .NET to the user's machine are over and done with.  It has been included in Windows for 7 years already, it is as pointless as including the Windows operating system in your installer.  .NET 4.0 and up automatically install themselves.  You make it a prerequisite, something that the user needs to take care of.  Just like the user needs to have a proper version of Windows on the machine, enough RAM and disk space, etcetera.

Comment: When you say "You make it a prerequisite", do you mean to check radiobox - "Download prerequisite from vendor's web site"  yes?