# Pack data files with an application in c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

So I want to create a C# application that can be transmitted to users which can then run an "exe" file copying the data files. Therefore, the application should contain at least to things:

1. The "exe" file
2. The files containing the data

The data in the application will be in most cases a directory with files and subfolders. My concern is how to store this data. I was thinking about storing the data in ".bin" files while being able to read the data with the exe file and place the files/folders in the correct structure, but I don't know exactly how would I do that with files and folders. Does anyone have any suggestions ? Is there a better way? Do you have any recommended reads ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you compile in either debug or release mode, there will be an .exe file in the bin/debug or bin/release folder for your project together with all the project files. You can move that to whatever machine with the .NET framework installed and run the .exe.

If you want to make an actualy executable, that's more difficult to do. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962816/compile-to-stand-alone-exe-for-c-sharp-app-in-visual-studio-2010%20%22this%22%20other%20thread%20for%20inspiration%20on%20that.) post for more inspiration on that.

Comment: The data files will not be a part of the project files. What I want to do is that I can have an app where I can select the folder and then generate the exe file that reads the data files and copies them to a selected directory on another computer. I don't necessarily want that the data files are in the exe file, but in some bin files.

Answer (score 0):

If your build is meant for distribution, better compile it on **Release** mode. 
You will find the assemblies on your **project_folder/bin/Release**.

You may want to copy all contents in the release folder by compressing it, or better yet, using an installer compilation tool, like **InnoSetup** - http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php/, that is free and will do your application installer just fine.