# How to publish / compile program without needing users to install it

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Compile to a stand-alone executable (.exe) in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035083/compile-to-a-stand-alone-executable-exe-in-visual-studio)

I finished my application, but I would like to know how I can make the users run it directly from an .exe without needing to run a setup.exe
I am using visual studio ultimate 2010.

Thanks for the help. I didn't find anything on google.

Comment: How complex is your app and what kind of IO permissions does it need? Which deployment mechanisms have you looked at? For example: is ClickOnce out of the picture?

Comment: This is a repost of this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035083/compile-to-a-stand-alone-executable-exe-in-visual-studio Do any of the solutions work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste your solution outputs in a directory "`bin\Release`" file, but be aware that you should have the release configuration at your project when you build, so not give the user your debug version "`bin\debug`". 

Note that you don't have to copy the whole files in the release directory, just the nessesary resources *if any* and the `.dll` files.. and don't include the `.pdb` files, and `.exe.manifest`.

Another thing that you are here assumes that the user has the framework installed in his machine, if that is not the case then you can just create a new [Setup Project](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/58021-deploying-a-c#-application-visual-studio-setup-project/)

Comment: A tip for your future release builds: you can manage to omit debug related files per build configuration, so they needn't be there in order for someone to copy by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You can just locate the executable file (and any local dependencies) in the build output folder (generally `bin\release`, when configured to release build, relative to the project directory.)

Depending on what other resources your application depends upon, simply deploying in this manner may mean your application doesn't "just work", though; be careful to understand what kind of environment your application needs to run in prior to deployment and take all necessary precautions.