# Can you create a .exe with Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, winforms, publish

I know that visual studio has A LOT of required files to launch anything through an executable, is there a way I could create an .exe that doesn't require all the excess files like you would with a JAR file?  I know they are completely different but I'm just trying to find out what we can do other than installing the application on the users PC.  Thanks!

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/2035104](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2035104)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a way I could create an .exe that doesn't require all the excess files like you would with a JAR file?

Partly.  If you're using VB.Net, you will always need to verify that the machine where you run your executable has the .NET Framework version which you target.

Most systems already have some .NET versions installed, which will allow your .exe to "just work" (provided you don't use any libraries apart from the framework).  Targeting an older .NET framework (like 3.5) will allow your exe to work on any system with .NET 3.5, without any other files.