# Can't run windows app on any other machine

Tags: c++, windows

I have recently written a fairly simple code for windows app, a 2048 game, including some basics such as icon, background and stuff, 4 buttons for different directions and 4x4 array of static windows for output. The Code isn't really "nice" but as I'm still learning I find it enough since it work ( at least on my PC ). I'm using default VS13 config, haven't changed anything after I installed it and the code is written in c++.
Codes can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/15y1daq2h3jm8p7/AADp0m1EfUJo3W2z315Zgd0Wa

Now what bugs me is that the program compiles with 0 warnings or errors and works just as I intended it when I run it either via debug or from desktop on my PC, but when I upload it to dropbox and want to start lets say on laptop then it doesn't work. 
Also if I try to compile the exact same code in Codeblocks I can't and there are warnings that many functions weren't declared in the scope.
Can any1 explain why is this happening and how can I fix it ?

Comment: Could you share the exact errors?

Comment: Missing msvcp120d.dll is the first error then after I downloaded that one it just says that my app isn't a valid win32 application.

Comment: Do you have VC++ runtime redistributable installed on the laptop?

Comment: I'm not so much into programming to know things like that, did you mean VC++ redistributable for VS13? I just downloaded it and installed and still the same error (0xc000007b). Well now it says the app wasn't able to start correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic problem you are facing is that you are trying to compile the code outside of the Visual Studio environment for a VCPP code that you have written.

When you debug the code using Visual Studio, all the required files/dependencies are injected during compilation.

I'd recommend packaging the code using Visual Studio and try running the exe on your laptop.

Make sure you have the correct version of VC++ runtime environment installed on your target machine. (You can optionally also include the setup with your packaged setup.)

---

From here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20890610/1477051

> As you can see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh.aspx), the MSVCP DLL is the platform's
>   implementation of the C++ Standard Library. In short what that means
>   is you cannot distribute your application without needing the "stuff"
>   that these libraries provide. All compilers regardless of platform
>   would need some kind of implementation of the Standard Library.
>   Typically this is distributed in the form of libraries.
>
> However you can distribute your application so that the "stuff" is
>   built in to your program directly, rather than being shipped in a
>   separate DLL. In order to do this, you must statically link your
>   application to the Standard Library.
>
> There are a few ways to accomplish this. One way is in Project
>   Settings. In "Configuration Properties" > "C/C++ Code Generation" >
>   "Runtime Library", choose "Multithreaded (/MT)" as opposed to
>   "Mutithreaded (Static)".
>
> By the way, the "D" in "MSVCP120D.dll" you mentioned above means
>   "Debug." This means that you are trying to distribute a debug build of
>   your program. You should (almost) never do this. Distribute release
>   builds instead.

Comment: Wow, ok now I learned something really useful thanks, but now I am getting an error in a file I never even heard of any chance you can assist me with this? I've changed the Runtime Library to /MT

Comment: 1>------ Build started: Project: w2048, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  2048Main.cpp
1>libcpmtd.lib(stdthrow.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReportW referenced in function "void __cdecl std::_Debug_message(wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,unsigned int)" (?_Debug_message@std@@YAXPB_W0I@Z)
1>c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\w2048\Debug\w2048.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Comment: Setting compiler flag /MTd (multiThreaded debug runtime library) will solve the problem.

Comment: You are building a "debug" configuration. Debug configurations run only on a machine with Visual Studio installed. Build a "release" configuration when using /MT and to be able to run the program on other machines.

Comment: I did, but I have to ask what's the difference between release and debug configs ?

Comment: By default, Debug includes debug information in the compiled files (allowing easy debugging) while Release usually has optimizations enabled.