# How to launch visual studio (.exe) program so, other people can use it?

Tags: c#, window, console-application

I don't have a code. I have built the program in the console application and window application but I don't know how to launch those programs.

Comment: The `.exe` will be found in the project folder. For example: you have a project on your desktop. The filepath would be `C:\Users\Me\ProjectName\ProjectName\bin\Debug`. Depending on how you compiled it, the folder may be `Release` instead of `Debug`. You can find the `.exe` within these files. See also: [Compile to a stand-alone executable (.exe) in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035083/compile-to-a-stand-alone-executable-exe-in-visual-studio)

Comment: Try to read some tutorials before asking here https://stackify.com/cross-platform-net-core-apps/  Such questions are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

You need to publish them,

Open PowerShell in the project folder, type `dotnet publish` and run it.
You will get a published version that you can run.