# Can't embed EPPlus.dll into my exe

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, embed

I need to embed EPPlus.dll to my standalone exe app. I don't want it to be copied along the exe. Apparently icluding it as an assembly resource would solve my problem. I found many decriptions on how to do it. For e.g. I performed all the below:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x-KK7bmo1AM

http://adamthetech.com/2011/06/embed-dll-files-within-an-exe-c-sharp-winforms/

[Embedding DLL's into .exe in in Visual C# 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920920/embedding-dlls-into-exe-in-in-visual-c-sharp-2010)

Still I get `Could not load file or assembly 'EPPlus.dll'...`

Can you please give me some idea as I have never done something like this before?

P.S.: I use VS C# 2010 Express

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: If that video doesn't work, and the others methods don't work... then I would hazard a guess that you didn't follow correctly.

Comment: @Peter It's in the Q...

Comment: @PaulZahra I did re-checked it several times and I'm sure I followed all the steps correctly. Otherwise I wouldn't even think about posting this question.

Comment: @fishmong3r there must be more information? any way using ILMerge should solve your problem i have used it many times in the past, the only time it fails is when you are using WPF...

Comment: @Peter I've read about this ILMerge stuff, but couldn't find example codes which makes it hard to me to do it from scratch. Can you please help me out with some link/code?

Comment: The method in the youtube video is simple enough, and should work!

Comment: @PaulZahra Indeed, but again, it's not working in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try having a look at this in your application:

In the program.cs main method:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);
```

Create the event:

```
private static Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Name.StartsWith("MyAssembly,"))
    {
        return Assembly.Load(Properties.Resources.MyAssembly_Dll);
    }
    return null;
}
```

I am using something similar for dynamically loading an assembly that requires other assemblies that have not yet been loaded and so I load them as required.

Comments welcome.

Comment: I added this event: `private static Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.Name.StartsWith("EPPlus"))
            {
                return Assembly.Load(Properties.Resources.EPPlus);
            }
            return null;
        }`
It doesn't work. I can't use it like EPPlus.dll as if I add it to the resources like an existing file, it removes the extension.

Answer (score 0):

Download ILMerge from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17630) then install ILMerge.

After that you should have the following file `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\ILMerge\ILMerge.exe` or `C:\Program Files\Microsoft\ILMerge\ILMerge.exe` if you are on a 32bit system.

Then you execute ILMerge.exe with the following parameters /out:OutputExeFile.exe InputExeFile.exe dllfile.dll

After that ILMerge should have merged InputExeFile.exe and dllfile.dll and stored the result in OutputExeFile.exe

if you just run the ilmerge you will get the following help

> Usage: ilmerge [/lib:directory]* [/log[:filename]] [/keyfile:filename
>   [/delaysign]] [/internalize[:filename]]
>   [/t[arget]:(library|exe|winexe)] [/closed] [/ndebug] [/ver:version]
>   [/copyattrs [/allowMultiple] [/keepFirst]] [/xmldocs] [/attr:filename]
>   [/targetplatform:[,] | /v1 | /v1.1 | /v2 | /v4]
>   [/useFullPublicKeyForReferences] [/wildcards] [/zeroPeKind]
>   [/allowDup:type]* [/union] [/align:n] /out:filename 
>   [...]

Comment: Where do you define the dll to be embedded?

Comment: dllfile.dll is the dll that should be embeded, if you have mutiple you can use /wildcards and use *.dll or just list them one after the other..

Comment: And I have to do this process every single time I build a new version of the exe, right?

Comment: ILMerge error: `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\ILMerge>ilmerge.exe /out:RSMailer.exe "C:\Users\user\Google Drive\x\Projects\RSMailer\bin\Release\RSMailer.exe
" "c:\Users\user\Google Drive\x\Projects\RSMailer\Resources\EPPlus.dll"
An exception occurred during merging:
Unresolved assembly reference not allowed: System.Core.
   at System.Compiler.Ir2md.GetAssemblyRefIndex(AssemblyNode assembly)
   at System.Compiler.Ir2md.GetTypeRefIndex(TypeNode type)
   at System.Compiler.Ir2md.WriteTypeDefOrRefEncoded(BinaryWriter target, TypeNode type)`

Comment: @fishmong3r did you try google that error? http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2010/06/02/ilmerge---unresolved-assembly-reference-not-allowed-system.core.aspx

Comment: OK, I added the config file and it's running. Actually I initiated the command 15 minutes ago. I suppose it's a bit longer then expected. The new exe has been created meanwhile with 0KB in size.

Comment: I have no idea what file sizes you are working with but 15 minutes is extreme. for me it takes a few seconds

Comment: The exe and the dll together is no larger than 2.5 MB.

Comment: I tried it again, but after 40 minutes I killed the process.