# Create a stand-alone C# executable that references a 3rd-party DLL?

Tags: c#, dll, exe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Embedding DLLs in a compiled executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189549/embedding-dlls-in-a-compiled-executable)

I would like to make a stand alone program in C#, I have a referenced dll, so I can't just copy the exe from bin/release/.exe, I have to copy both the exe and and the dll.

I want users to be able to download and run the exe, not both the exe and the dll. By stand alone I mean just the exe, without an installer.

Comment: I mean you are meant to ask a question. You did not do that.

Comment: I hope you know that all of the answers that you have gotten so far are in the above link.

Comment: Odd that nobody ever considers setup.exe

Comment: I edit the title to "add" a question. Don't forget to go through an accept any questions with suitable answers and/or delete old localized questions with no suitable answers ..

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [ILMERGE](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx) (and [download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=17630)):

> ILMerge is a utility for merging multiple .NET assemblies into a single .NET assembly. It works on executables and DLLs alike and comes with several options for controlling the processing and format of the output. See the accompanying documentation for details.

---

Alternatively, look at other deployment options, such as [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce):

> ClickOnce is a Microsoft technology that enables the user to install and run a Windows application by clicking a link in a web page. (Such applications are known as Smart clients.) ClickOnce is a component of Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 and later, supports deploying applications made with Windows Forms or Windows Presentation Foundation.

---

A third option is to create an installer - either with a [setup project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19x10e5c%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or a third party installer (there are many).

Comment: +1 Going the ilmerge route is "just so darn simple". However, this assumes that the other DLL is also managed/CLR and not accessed through COM-interop or anything fancy.

Comment: @pst - Fair point, though I think it a fair assumption.

Comment: I do to. Just adding a disclaimer :) Although the documentation does say "merge [..] .NET assemblies into [..] .NET assembly".

Answer (score 3):

Embed your dll as a resource to your executable,

attach to `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` event,

And read your dll from resource and return it, in the event.

Comment: This is the way I would go with. Recommended reading (including comments): http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx