# Packing third party DLL into Windows service

Tags: c#, windows, dll, service, installation

I am writing a Windows Service for my college and I am using one third party library to help with scheduling. How do I package this DLL into my service so that only the .exe file needs to be deployed on a server and installed? I don't want the DLL to have to be copied into the same directory as the .exe every time. Thanks!

Comment: you need to create an installer : http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-ai-ext-vs.html

Comment: An interesting thread about embedding DLLs as resources here... [on this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189549/embedding-dlls-in-a-compiled-executable)