# building an exe including dependencies

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I'm fairly new to C#. I'm trying to write and deploy a small command line app that relies on the CommandlineParser library: http://commandline.codeplex.com

There are no errors when building it and surprisingly enough the program there are no errors when executing the exe either. However, when I copy the exe file to another location on my computer and try to run it, it complains that it doesn't find the commandlineparser dependency.

I'm using VS2012 and tried the build as well as the debug version. The same error occurs both times.

Is there a way to include the commandlineparser library into the exe? If not, which file(s) would I have to combine to the exe file?

Sorry if these questions are too simple.

Comment: You will probably find the library needs to be in the same directory and the program will work as expected.

Comment: Have you searched *embed .dll in C# application* or similar? https://www.google.com/#output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=embed+dll+in+c%23+exe&oq=embed+&gs_l=hp.3.0.35i39l2j0i20l2.1253.2422.0.4685.6.6.0.0.0.0.138.609.5j1.6.0.crnk_timepromotiona..0.0...1.1.17.psy-ab.ztMO0XzY_Fo&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47883778,d.aWc&fp=82fdc25a886fd9a7&biw=1280&bih=807 There are many versions of this here on SO too.

Comment: @JMK Thanks for the pointer... found the dll which made it work. +1 if i could... new to so too. Cheers anyway

Comment: @pandita why don't you post what worked for you as an Answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to copy the library itself as well to any location you want to run the executable. If your idea is to have them packed in one file you'll have to use a tool in order to merge them, see:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4043653/812598

Comment: Ok, for those new to VS2012, you'll find a file ending with .dll in the same folder as you'll find your .exe. You need to have both files in the same folder to be able to execute them.