# In Visual Studio, how to build components into final version?

Tags: c#, .net, components, krypton-toolkit

I've downloaded and installed the Krypton Toolkit for Visual Studio.

https://github.com/ComponentFactory/Krypton

Is it possible, to build my final solution with these libaries? I don't want install Krypton Toolkit on every PC, where the software will be used.

Comment: Maybe this can help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189549/embedding-dlls-in-a-compiled-executable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont have to install Krypton toolkit on ever PC, Just include **ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.dll** with your Setup/Bin file(s).

Also here is an [***Answer***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22996201/can-krypton-toolkit-run-on-other-computers-without-toolkit-installed/23016421#23016421) to a simliar question