# How to avoid DLL Dependencies?

Tags: c#, qt, dll, dependencies, interop

I'm developing a communication Dll which depends on qt.
When I try to use this dll in my C# code I get an error which I found was due to missing some qt's dll.
After including these qt dll's the project work.
My question is:
How can I link these qt libraries in Visual Studio in order to avoid including the qt dll's"?

Comment: Try this one:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189549/embedding-dlls-in-a-compiled-executable

it goes for executables but perhaps it'll give you some ideas

Comment: Just to confirm: The DLL is a C/C++ one, NOT a C# assembly, right?

Comment: @BartoszJanik, it's very interesting! But it's actually not clear, will this violate LGPL license or not :) From your link: "For the unmanaged code (here: UnmanagedService.dll) you just link in the DLL as an Existing Item and set the Build Action to Embedded Resource. To access its functions use the DllImport attribute as usual"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a statically linked version of the communication DLL. If there is no such version you need to stick to the DLLs.

Answer (score 1):

You can link `Qt` statically only under `GPL` or commercial license. And most of all you won't do this. So, just use dynamic linking and stay with Qt `LGPL` license, which allows commercial using of your software.