# Programmatically access embedded dll and save it to GAC?

Tags: c#, dll, console-application, gac

I'd like to ship my program only with an executable, so I'm using [Costura.Fody](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20306095/880472) to embed resources in my assembly. But theres a problem.. I'm programmatically adding some assemblies (which also would be embedded) (b.e `MyDll.dll`) to the GAC:

```
using System.EnterpriseServices.Internal;

Publish publish = new Publish();
publish.GacInstall("C:\Temp\MyDll.dll"); //path to my dll
```

It would work normally if I would ship the dll's separately with the exe but is there a way I can obtain a path from my executing program of `MyDll.dll` assembly which is embedded in the executable and save it like that to the GAC?

Comment: Any reason you want it in the GAC? If not try using Assembly.Load() to load the assemblies directly from the byte arrays embedded in your file. Methods like GetAssembly will not work with byte arrays. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.load%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: You should not use the GAC, unless you want to end up in dll-hell :)

Comment: Is it possible to load the byte array of your embedded assembly and write it to a "save place" and then load it into the GAC ? I am not quite sure what you are trying to accomplish with the GAC

Answer (score -1):

Your dll will be in the application bin folder, so you can find it using

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

and run code to register it in post install

One more thing worth mentioning: The dll will not be installed if it is not signed