# How to add and then extract Dll from C# just before the program starts?

Tags: c#

So I have a simple written program in C# (.exe) but it requires one of Dll's to be loaded and extracted into specific or temp folder so the program will load correctly.

What's the easiest way to achieve it ?

Comment: Is this unmanaged DLL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ship the DLL in the same folder as the EXE.

Comment: I want to embed it into exe file rather than having it in the same folder, is there any way I can do that ?

Comment: Oh! yes you can embed see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189549/embedding-dlls-in-a-compiled-executable