# How to pack published project to one EXE file in .NET

Tags: .net, installation

I have created a project that uses a couple of DLLs and EXE in .NET.

And I see that some applications are packed like ***into 1 EXE***.

**Which technology I have to know to do it?
Are their any tools to do it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to include DLL and EXE files using just Visual Studio, as long as you add an installer project then these dependencies can be included and copied in the install folder for use by your app.

Check out this tutorial: http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-ai-ext-vs.html, specifically section 7 'Project Dependencies'.

This response covers some good options for including as a single, non-installer exe: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4043653/1011603