# visual basic: how to compile dll, USB driver into my exe?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am using visual studio 2015. 
In my application, there are:
1, D2XX driver from: http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/D2XX.htm 
2, Newtonsoft.Json.dll

How to compile into one exe file for 64 bit and 32 bit windows machines?

**UPDATE**

I used "Publish" function in visual studio and got some files (see the pic), but I have no idea which file users should use to install my app? setup OR all of them?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Embedding DLLs in a compiled executable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189549/embedding-dlls-in-a-compiled-executable)

Comment: The user uses "setup" to install, but they will need the applications file folder present. An easier way to achieve all of this is to use the Install Shield Wizard software (separate download)