# Is packaging JSON serialization dependencies into binary still a good idea for a .NET Core library?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

When I've built a shared .NET library in the past (for internal use, not a public library), I've embedded a serialization library (usually Newtonsoft) as a resource and used assembly resolving to load it in a manner similar to [Embedding DLLs in a compiled executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189549/embedding-dlls-in-a-compiled-executable). I've done this so the users of the library aren't forced to worry about the version of Newtonsoft that the library was built with.

In a .NET Core world, is this still a good approach? It seems like with the deep inclusion of NuGet, it might not be needed anymore, but I haven't built a large enough number of .NET Core applications to know how bad dependency graph management can get.

Comment: What different about serialization dependency and any other dependency? Do you have a requirement that the whole application has to be a single executable file?

Comment: The main difference is that serialization and logging are two dependencies that almost every project will have. I have spent many days fighting N dependencies that all specify a different version of log4net (or Newtonsoft) in the NuGet specification, usually resorting to assembly binding redirects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have moved away from doing that.  The ability to specify dependencies and which specific versions of them are required makes it more explicit to consumers (ours is only for our team) that there's a dependency.  Having dependencies being less explicit has lead to headaches for us, especially with larger applications as keeping your binding redirects all happy can become an issue. Might as well keep it easy for yourself to remember that you might need some other package and which version has been successfully integrated by using the nuget dependency management in the nuspec.

Comment: It's definitely worth a try. Hopefully it doesn't end like NPM :)