# WinForm App not working on others computer

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, deployment, publish

I have created a simple clone FM Radio from http://csharptutorialsfree.blogspot.my/2013/10/c-radio-streaming-bug-fixed.html

But there is one problem :

When I published / deploy my radio followed exactly from this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=USfQzZX-ytQand

When I run my radio app on others computer(which doesn't have visual studio installed). Windows Media Player inside my application not working(doesn't produce any stream music). But it's works on my work computer(That has Visual Studio installed).

Can anyone help me with this, Thanks.

Comment: What is "not functioning"? What goes wrong? Details!

Comment: @MrLister hello, ok ... On my work computer, I can listen my stream music produce from Windows Media Player (everything was fine, application still working). But when I open my application on my sister's computer (which doesn't have visual studio installed). The apps still can open , but can't listen to any stream music

Comment: Does it not work on windows 10 computers?

Comment: @shad0wk i dont have windows 10

Comment: Try to open your stream link in any internet browser to see that there is nothing block the URL (any antivirus programs, for example).

Comment: @WanFai It may not work if the other computer doesn't have the Windows Media Player resources, `.dll` files.

Comment: @Jackdaw radio link seems to works fine on chrome but for Internet explorer, it force you to download the stream url.

Comment: @shad0wk I thought when I export my application, Visual Studio will automatically export everything into setup?.

Comment: @WanFai It doesn't embed the `.dll`'s. You have to make it embed them. If the system doesn't support or have one of the `.dll`s then your code won't work.

Comment: @shad0wk so, that means i have to add references (the dll)to the project and move it to the Release and Debug folder? Is it ?

Comment: @Wan Fai Yeah that will work. Or you can [embed them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189549/embedding-dlls-in-a-compiled-executable).