# How do I deal with multiple project dependencies when wishing to output a single .dll class library

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll

I have my main solution wish is comprised of 4 projects. There is a precedence chain between my 4 projects, that is 1 needs 2, 2 needs 3 etc. Also, some of these projects use Nuget packages.

Like this:

[Project Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQUBU.png)

Now I can get my MainPointOfEntry.dll, and include it my a external solution and it works fine, but I don't see how it knows where to find the dependent .dlls (maybe it is somehow looking in the same solution folder)

[External Solution with referenced dll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJZcS.png)

So my single entry point works fine, but how does it know where to find the dlls of which MainPointOfEntry depends?

I feel if I was to make a copy of MainPointOfEntry.dll and create a solution on a different computer it would not work?

Sorry about this badly phrased question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how does it know where to find the dlls of which MainPointOfEntry depends?

It doesn't. `MainPointOfEntry` does.

> I feel if I was to make a copy of MainPointOfEntry.dll and create a solution on a different computer it would not work?

Depends on if you have embedded the library in output or not. If you have added your dependency and configured to be an embedded resource It will work. If not, you need to copy these too.

Comment: Hmm. So does that mean I will need to add both a reference and an existing item as an embedded resource? So as MainPointOfEntry requires various references, I will need to also add them to the project as embedded resources?

Comment: If you want to embed a reference check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189549/embedding-dlls-in-a-compiled-executable)