# Embed dlls and contents into exe in monogame

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

In other C# projects such as `Window Forms` and `WPF`, I can just copy the built exe to other environment with .net and run without errors.

However, in `MonoGame`, the exe file requires a lot of dlls and needs the content folder to run successfully.

Is there a way to include the dlls and contents inside the exe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, it can be achieved by 2 steps.

1. Embedding the dlls.
2. Including the contents.

**Embedding the dlls**

This can be easily achieved by installing [Costura.Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Costura) using NuGet.

Type the following line to the Package Manager Console

```
Install-Package Costura.Fody
```

Source: [Embedding DLLs in a compiled executable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20306095/3917161).

**Including the contents**

1. Copy your compiled content files (`.xnb` files and other contents) to your `Content` folder.
2. Go to the project property page and add your compiled content files to your resources.
3. Replace the code below:

   ```
   public Game1()
   {
       graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
       Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
   }
   ```

   with

   ```
   public Game1()
   {
       graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
       ResourceContentManager resxContent;
       resxContent = new ResourceContentManager(Services, Resources.ResourceManager);
       Content = resxContent;
   }
   ```
4. Finished! You can now load content using the old method

   ```
   Content.Load<Texture2D>("Image1");
   ```

Source: [Loading Content Within a Game Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff604975.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)