# C# - How to embed DLL into the project?

Tags: c#, dll, embed

I'm working on a project in Visual Studio where I need to embed 2 DLLs.
So far, I've been referencing those DLLs, but then I cannot use them without actually having the files in the same folder as my EXE.
Obviously, I want my users to only need the EXE to use them, without having to download the DLLs as well.
The thing I tried to far is following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lx2tSY4joDg
But this is only for one file and the tutorial sadly **didn't** work for me.

What can I do? Thanks!

**EDIT:** The project was built by Windows Forms Application.

Comment: Why not just have the referenced dlls copy to the output folder on build?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not just supply the exe and the DLLs in a compressed archive format? Compressing them would save on bandwidth, and most users are familiar with how to unzip a file. A self-extracting archive would make it even easier.

Comment: @Kdawg In terms of size, my program's size isn't large at all. And in the archive thing, I don't want to let the users mess with extracting, but just keep everything simple, as the software meant to simplify a process in the computer.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you aren't using .NET Core, it is really easy to do this now with [Costura.Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Costura) (As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20306095/947986)).

Just add the nuget package like this, and it's basically turnkey from there!

`Install-Package Costura.Fody`

Comment: Didn't work - I tried executing the command in the directory where all the 3 files are, but Windows Powershell returned an error. http://i.imgur.com/0JyOa6j.png

Comment: @avi12 You run this command within the NuGet console of say Visual Studio. From my understanding, you cannot run this command outside in say Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use [ILMerge](http://microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17630)

After you build with Visual Studio, you can merge the libraries like this:

```
ilmerge /target:winexe /out:MergedAssembly.exe VSBuiltAssembly.exe Lib1.dll Lib2.dll
```

Comment: Still didn't work for me. I'm probably doing something wrong. I put all three files in the same directory, executed the command, the folder was refreshed, but when testing it (I put the EXE in the Desktop) - didn't work.

Comment: I even followed up the following tutorial and it didn't work for some reason: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a_r3tQ06xpE