# IsAssignableFrom returns false when type is loaded from embedded resource

Tags: c#, dll

I have an executable that I'd like to be able to share stand-alone, without having to make sure the dependent DLLs get copied. To achieve that, I've embedded the DLLs into the executable as resource files, using answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6362414/778617). So far it's been going well and I'm able to access the interface - call it InterfaceA - in the DLL correctly. The application is also meant to load a 3rd party DLL, specified at runtime, which contains a class implementing InterfaceA. I use reflection to find a type implementing InterfaceA and use `Activator.CreateInstance` to create an instance.

The problem is that as I'm iterating over the available types in the 3rd party DLL, `typeof(InterfaceA).IsAssignableFrom(thirdPartyType)` always returns false. This is not the case, however, when my DLL is a regular reference and isn't embedded as a resource. It seems that just because the DLL is embedded as a resource, InterfaceA is treated as a different type. However, `thirdPartyType.GetInterface(typeof(InterfaceA).FullName)` always returns what seems to be the correct interface type.

How can I load the embedded DLL so InterfaceA isn't treated as a different type, or use it with the third party types so `IsAssignableFrom` and `CreateInstance` both work correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem you are facing is assembly identity difference between having an assembly embedded and referenced.
Check versions. Are you sure third party assembly is built against the same version of assembly containing the InterfaceA which you load from resources?

EDIT: based on discussion in comments, the problem is potentially in the use of `LoadFrom()`. Using the `LoadFile(string path)`, I was able to execute the scenario described in the question successfully.

Comment: Right now I'm testing against a "third party DLL" that I made myself, so right now everything is using the exact same interface DLL. I do notice now that `typeof(InterfaceA).Module.FullyQualifiedName` returns "<Unknown>" whereas the same check against the third party types returns the path to the interface DLL on my machine.

Comment: Where are you embedding from? `Bin\$configuration`?

Comment: I'm not positive I understand the question. I added the interface DLL as a file resource to the project. I then use the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` event handler to make sure it gets loaded in time. The process is detailed much better in the answer I linked to in my question.

Comment: Sure. When you added it as file resource, from which folder did you drag it or selected it? Because if you dragged it from e.g. `bin\Debug` and then trying to run "thirdparty" built against the one compiled in `bin\Release` you'll might see this or similar behavior.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. The Release version is being used across the board. The interface DLL is preexisting and isn't being modified or rebuilt as part of this project.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/YhQmPdwZ here's my example project 7zipped and then base64ed. Decode with e.g. http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp (it has an option to download as a file)

Comment: Amazing! The difference (besides the fact that you used Linq and I didn't) is that you loaded the assembly using LoadFile, and I used LoadFrom. That seems to have made all the difference. I'll have to do some research into what the difference between the two methods is. Update your answer with this info please, and I'll accept it.