# c#, how to add a binary dependency file safe as resource to the EXE in designer

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

my visual studio project has some includes (i use the .net framework 4.6.1).
So I wanted to do a loader in .net 2.0 for unpacking the needed files without admin rights into a user folder with the EXE together.

My idea was to add them as type "FILE" resource into the "loader" project and then extract them as a file again in the user directory together with the .net 4.6.1 EXE. As soon I add one of the files to my NET 2.0 loader project as resource in the designer, the whole project is broken and spits out errors, which I do not understand.

How I can add a complex file as a resource in my project (DLL / EXE)? Simple TEXT-Files work so far. (The extracting routine works also). I get the error right after adding a binary dependency file (DLL) like "System.Data.dll". It says after adding the resource that I have a wrong reference or something alike. The project becomes immediately unusable after it with that error persisting. If I delete the file out of the resource again, the error persists. I have to start all over again with the project.
Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do... are you trying to add a dependency dll as embedded resource inside the exe? Because, you can load those even without extracting them. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6362414/395685

Comment: I am curious how would I load them if the new .NET Framework would not be installed on the targeting computer?

Comment: Not sure that's possible... either target a lower framework or set a minimum requirement.