# Embedding dlls into exe with Mono support with Fody

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mono, fody

Well my question is almost similar to *[Embedding DLLs in a compiled executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189549/embedding-dlls-in-a-compiled-executable)* but the very great answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20306095/4427870) looses the compatiblity with mono runtime, though it works on windows.

So how can I use `Fody` (`Costura`) and also maintain mono compatibility. Their docs at https://github.com/Fody/Costura#contents read:

> CosturaUtility is a class that gives you access to initialize the
>   Costura system manually in your own code. This is mainly for scenarios
>   where the module initializer doesn't work, such as libraries and Mono.
>
> To use, call CosturaUtility.Initialize() somewhere in your code, as
>   early as possible.
>
> ```
> class Program {
>     static Program() {
>         CosturaUtility.Initialize();
>     }
>
>     static void Main(string[] args) { ... }
> }
> ```

but even after initialising `ConturaUtility` manually it does not support mono runtime.

I dont think the error log is relevant but here it is:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'CommandLine, Version=2.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=de6f01bd326f8c32' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'CommandLine, Version=2.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=de6f01bd326f8c32'
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'CommandLine, Version=2.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=de6f01bd326f8c32' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'CommandLine, Version=2.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=de6f01bd326f8c32'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code at the start of Main() in your Program:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, args) => {
   String resourceName = "AssemblyLoadingAndReflection." +
      new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name + ".dll";
   using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName)) {
      Byte[] assemblyData = new Byte[stream.Length];
      stream.Read(assemblyData, 0, assemblyData.Length);
      return Assembly.Load(assemblyData);
   }
};
```

Reference: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/microsoft_press/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition/