# How to create Standalone Executable File of my project that contain all required resources?

Tags: c#, winforms, installation, executable, external-links

I have created one application using **Windows Form** in **C#**,I have use many **external library** as well as **other resources** like images,mp3 etc., Now I have need to deliver this as **standalone executable** (single executable) that **directly** run on client  machine ,They **no need to install** it.

So,I need your help for that,please help me to create standalone executable file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think Costura is the way to go. SEE HERE : https://stackoverflow.com/a/20306095/6399544

Comment: I have tried that but it doesn't work for me

Comment: *"no need to install it"* - I would reconsider this requirement. Installers packages are typical way to deliver a product (or zip package, to download everything with one click). The only purpose of not having to run installer is to create a portable version to avoid hassles with installing libraries. But having portable version as single exe .. why?

Comment: i don't to force my user to install the software , Just Download it and use it as portable software

Comment: @HirenPatel If I solved your issue, could you please validate my answer ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to incorporate ressource in your .exe you can use the property

> embedded ressource

Go in visual studio

> -> Click on your ressource (bmp, mp3 etc ..)
>   -> Go into properties
>   -> Generated Action -> embedded ressource

Then you can use your ressource like this :

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("PROJECTNAME.Resources.RESSOURCENAME")
```

Answer (score 0):

As Cesar already mentioned it, Costura works really fine once set up correctly (using same .NET Versions etc.)