# Can I Create a Common Dll which comprises of many third party dlls and use it in some other application as a single package?

Tags: c#, .net, dll

Im creating a Custom dll(Which is common for LOgInterface) which includes various third party dll such as NLOg and Log4Net.Now Im Using this Custom dll in some other windows Application as a single package(eg:CommonI.dll).Will my aplication work without including thirdparty dll such as log4net?

Comment: You are looking for [ILMerge](https://github.com/dotnet/ILMerge).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Embedding DLLs in a compiled executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189549/embedding-dlls-in-a-compiled-executable)