# .exe file fails when my project contains a reference as solution of another project - winform c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, reference, exe

My winform application contains a lot of references.I was able to create it's single executable file by installing [Fody and Costura](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189549/embedding-dlls-in-a-compiled-executable). But now my app need to add solution of another project as a reference to it. Now when creating a new exe it is not working. It means that this newly added external reference is not including in the exe. Can you help how to create an exe which should include an external project solution as reference?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with "not working"? Do you get any error or warning while compiling?

Comment: when double clicking on exe , comes nothing.

Comment: Did you try to run it in debug mode from Visual Studio?

Comment: yes both debug and release mode are working.

Comment: What are .NET versions of your project and additional libraries? Are they same? Are both x86 or 64bit?

Comment: I can run the exe file when it is in release folder of project. when I copy it to other location it is not working

Comment: Did you copy all dlls from release folder too?

Comment: release folder contains Demo.exe,Demo.exe.config and Demo.pdb files only. when I copy these three it is working. But I want to execute the app with single exe file. Previously I can achieve it by installing costura and foddy. But now it is not working with external project solution as reference. That is my issue

Comment: why don't you try publishing it to your desired location