# Embed DLL in .NET executable

Tags: .net, dll, embed

I use a DLL for certain designs in my .NET Application. How can I embed this DLL into my .NET executable to make my application standalone. I'd like to be able to do it in Visual Studio, without any complicated 3rd party Applications

EDIT: I decided to use ILMerge to merge my dll & executable because its usage is quite easy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Embedding DLLs in a compiled executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189549/embedding-dlls-in-a-compiled-executable)