# Fody is only supported on MSBuild 16 and above. Current version: 15

Tags: c#, fody, visual-studio-2017-build-tools, fody-propertychanged

Visual Studio 2017 let me know there was an upgrade to Fody version 5 this morning.  I accepted and did a NuGet package update of both Fody and PropertyChanged.Fody.

Now, my project/solution will no longer build.

The error is:

"Fody is only supported on MSBuild 16 and above. Current version: 15."

I tried uninstalling, shutting down VS, and reinstalling to no avail.

Comment: Roll back to the previous nuget package version?

Comment: https://github.com/Fody/Fody/issues/679

Answer (score 94):

Please downgrade Fody to version 4.2.1.

Comment: What is the last version of Fody supporting Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: In my case I had to downgrade PropertyChanged.Fody nuget from 3.0.1 to 2.6.1

Comment: If you use ReactiveUI, downgrade ReactiveUI.Fody to version 9.13.1. If you have VS17 15.9 or later, you can use this line in your csproj to lock the version: `<PackageReference Include="ReactiveUI.Fody" Version="[9.13.1]" />`

Comment: Although not as relevant, I came here because I was using Costura.Fody in a new csproj application.  Version 4.1.0 automatically uses Fody 6, but downgrading Costura.Fody to 3.3.3 worked for me.

Comment: If you're using Costura.Fody the last version compatible with 4.2.1 is 3.3.3

Answer (score 6):

For what it's worth - I ran into the same situation. A colleague added Fody with no other reason than to reduce the number of files created upon building.

Rather than deal with downgrading plugin versions or upgrading VS2017 to VS2019, I removed Fody from the project (as it had no real added value in the project).

Comment: I disagree with who-ever down-voted this: if you have a standard build environment, then if someone breaks the build by installing something that requires a VS upgrade, then the correct thing IS to remove the offending package... (until your standard build environment can be upgraded, of course).

Comment: yep. "to reduce the number of files created upon building" is not enough of a reason to take a dependency like Fody

Comment: All the time we spend trying to fix problems with build/Devops because Fody is much much times superior to time supposed saved in development. I don't recommend to use it.

Comment: another reason: It is expected that all developers become **Patrons**

Answer (score 4):

Upgrade to Visual Studio 2019  https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

Comment: It helps, but can I upgrade MSBuild only?

Comment: @StanislavPechezerov not that i know of

Comment: Who upgrades a VS version costing huge money just for a plugin?

Comment: @NitinSingh i agree. you should probably not use Fody

Comment: @NitinSingh visual studio Community edition is for free

Comment: I did. I was already on vstudio 2019. There is ANOTHER scenario leading to this problem, and I haven't figured out what.

Comment: @Barry raise an issue on github and ensure you follow the issue template https://github.com/Fody/Fody/issues/new?template=bug_report.md

Comment: I was able to resolve but thank you. Had to run a nuget restore on solution level to resolve

Comment: Who upgrades a VS version costing huge money just for a plugin?  Depends on the plugin and it's importance to the project requirements.