# How dll's are being picked

Tags: c#, dll, runtime

Small question : If a dll is being referenced from **C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6.1**, how does an application link/finds that during runtime? (or when launched without VS)?

Is it from GAC or the dll is copied into executable location at runtime?

Comment: [How runtime locates assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/how-the-runtime-locates-assemblies)

Answer (score 0):

The Framework you build with (4.6.1) has to be installed on the client (GAC) to run. Standard with normal Windows client/server.

If you want to *embed* the DLL in your EXE, have a look at [Embedding DLLs in a compiled executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189549/embedding-dlls-in-a-compiled-executable).

> I highly recommend to use Costura.Fody - by far the best and easiest
>   way to embed resources in your assembly. It's available as NuGet
>   package.
>
> ```
> Install-Package Costura.Fody
> ```
>
> After adding it to the project, it will automatically embed all
>   references that are copied to the output directory into your main
>   assembly. You might want to clean the embedded files by adding a
>   target to your project:
>
> ```
> Install-CleanReferencesTarget
> ```