# Package all Cefsharp file into executable?

Tags: c#, cefsharp

Is there any way to package all the files that are needed for a cefsharp executable into the executable itself? cause the application i'm working on is only meant to be run once so i don't want to clutter anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Embedding DLLs in a compiled executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189549/embedding-dlls-in-a-compiled-executable)

Comment: No, you need files on disk to keep CEF happy.  If one deployment file is essential then you do need to use the browser provided by the OS or create an installer.

Comment: You can embed them as resources and write the files to disk on first run. Self extracting zip is likely a lot easier.