# How to bundle c++ dll files?

Tags: dll

I am working on a Dot Net project and I am using C++ .dll files. I want the output of the program as just a single .exe file(which can easily be given to the customer) rather than multiple files. I have added those files under Properties>> Resources. However, when I tried adding them as Reference, I get the following error: Please make sure that the file is accessible and that is a valid assembly or COM component. 
Is there a way to bundle these file into one without using 3rd party tools/extensions? 
Plz advise.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may load them manually using `Assembly.Load` after reading the embeded resources with the raw binary.

Comment: They can't be loaded with Assembly.Load and cannot be embedded as a resource.  The OS requires them to be a file on disk.  Most Windows users expect them to be embedded in a program named Setup.exe

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189549/embedding-dlls-in-a-compiled-executable