# How to Create .exe of project of unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

How to create .exe of Unity project.I have created by build but it also creates extra folders .Such as dll files ,monobleeding Edge folder etc.While i need a single .exe file to give to my client. So he could simplry run and use it.

Comment: So it is a folder where the exe is inside. What is the problem? There is still no installation needed. If it is mandatory that you deliver a single file you can zip the folder.

Comment: You need to include all those files and folders where you built your project into, missing any will likely result in your game not working

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Embedding DLLs in a compiled executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189549/embedding-dlls-in-a-compiled-executable) ?

Comment: OK i will try this solution

Answer (score 1):

In order to make your unity3D project working outside of the Unity editor, you need to provide to your client the generated folder from the Unity Build because all the dll are needed by the runtime of the .exe.

Comment: Yes i know that but what to do to convert that folder to single .exe without displaying dll files

Comment: @aqeel do you want an installer?

Comment: @aqeel maybe: https://martin-klappacher.com/tutorial-windows-installer-for-your-unity-game/