# How do you make an exe run without needing all the dll files in the same directory?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, console-application, exe

So I'm trying to merge all of my DLL files into my exe if it's possible so I can run the exe without needing the DLL files in the same directory
I tried looking around for other people asking the same question but didn't really find anything helpful or anything I could personally follow.

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: When you publish your project, select the Deployment mode as "Self-contained" under Profile settings, and under the File Publish options, select "Produce single file". This will generate a single working .exe file for your project (along with a .pdb file)

Comment: Do you ask how to manage the GAC? To embed DLLs in the EXE? To use a shared folder? Or to run without any DLLs(?)? Otherwise what?

Comment: Yes, that, is possible: see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189549/embedding-dlls-in-a-compiled-executable and search the web for "*c# embed dll in executable*".

Comment: @Max - click on "Show all", and then you'll find the Deployment mode setting. Select "Self contained" Deployment mode. Then, select your specific Target Runtime. Once you select your Target Runtime, you'll see additional "File Publish options". In there, check the "Produce Single file" checkbox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Option 1: .NET Core >3.x, .NET 5

From [Single-file deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file#publish-a-single-file-app---sample-project-file) you can edit your project file to contain the following

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
    <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>
    <PublishReadyToRun>true</PublishReadyToRun>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Which corresponds to running the CLI tool:
`dotnet publish -r win-x64 -p:PublishSingleFile=true --self-contained true`

### Option 2: .NET Framework

Before the single-file deployment was available (in .NET Framework), I personally used [Fody Costura](https://github.com/Fody/Costura). Fody is an assembly weaver which, after installing, puts some commands into the MSBuild configuration of your project that enable you to do many things. One add-in is Costura, it weaves your dependencies into a single assembly.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution in this case is probably Fody as mentioned by Sorashi, but if you don't want to use it Visual Studio has another trick up its sleeve; the poorly-documented `IncludeAllContentForSelfExtract` property (in addition to everything from Option 1 in [Sorashi's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67949988/8705305)).

This allows you to include any `dll` dependencies from other projects in the same solution, as well as any external DLLs.

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- ...other properties... -->
    <IncludeAllContentForSelfExtract>true</IncludeAllContentForSelfExtract>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

This is an easy way to produce a single executable for a multi-project solution; but it isn't suitable for CLI applications so keep that in mind.

**Note that if you aren't using the `dotnet` CLI tool, you'll have to create a publish profile to use this.**

1. R-Click on the project that produces the `exe`, and select the **Publish...** option.
2. When prompted to choose a 'target', choose **Folder**.
   On the next page you'll be prompted for a filepath; you can just use `publish` if you don't want to dig through the `bin` directory.
3. Now that you have a publish profile, you should make sure that the configuration is correct.
   Click ***More actions** -> **Edit*** OR ***Show all settings***.
4. Make sure that **Deployment Mode** is set to **Self-contained**, and that **Produce single file** is enabled.
   [image: publish-profile-settings]
5. You can now click **Publish** in the top-right to create the executable.

If you want to use this publish profile in a CI script or something, you can use the `/p:PublishProfile` option with `dotnet publish` like this: `dotnet publish /p:PublishProfile="<PUBXML>"`
where `<PUBXML>` is the path to your profile's `pubxml` file, which is usually located in `<PROJECT>/Properties/PublishProfiles/FolderProfile.pubxml`