# Including .dll files in C# Forms Application

Tags: c#, forms, dll, exe, publish

I am using Visual Studio 2019 to build a C# Forms application. When publishing an .exe file from a Console application, I have the option to include all the .dll files into the .exe, meaning that users of my application only need to download one file. However, when publishing an .exe from a Forms application, I'm forced to include all of these .dll files independently:

[View of folder with .dll files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zogj5.png)

Is there a way to include these .dll files inside of the .exe so that I only have to send someone the .exe file for them to be able to run it, similar to how it's possible for Console applications?

EDIT: I've discovered that I was in .NET Core and should've been in .NET Framework. I'm relatively new to C# and wasn't aware of the differences. This issue is now resolved! If anyone runs into this problem, just copy-paste your code over to .NET Framework and listen to the instructions in the description.

Comment: There are many ways to package and deploy busted legacy framework applications and more modern .net core + applications, however its unclear what framework you are using, what you have chosen, why you are doing that way and what constraints you have.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the configuration settings during the build step to be "self-contained":

#### Using `dotnet` cli

```
dotnet publish -r win-x64 -c Release --self-contained
```

#### Using Visual Studio

1. Add `<PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>` to your project file.
2. On the **Solution Explorer** pane, right-click on the project you want to publish. Select **Publish**.

   [image: Soluition Explorer]

   If you don't already have a publishing profile, follow the instructions to create one and choose the **Folder** target-type.
3. Choose **Edit**.

   [image: Edit]
4. In the **Profile settings** dialog, set the following options:

   - Set **Deployment mode** to **Self-contained** or **Framework-dependent**.
   - Set **Target runtime** to the platform you want to publish to. (Must be something other than **Portable**.)
   - Select **Produce single file**.

   Choose **Save** to save the settings and return to the **Publish** dialog.

   [image: Profile Settings]
5. Choose **Publish** to publish your app as a single file.

For more information, see [Visual Studio Docs: Single file deployment and executable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file#publish-a-single-file-app---visual-studio).

---

Duplicate of [Embedding DLLs in a compiled executable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20306095/5779200)

Comment: [I'm seeing a significantly different publishing menu than you are.](https://i.imgur.com/vKQxXtS.png) I see the menu that you do when I'm publishing a console application.

Comment: Update: It turns out I was using .NET Core and I should've been using .NET Framework. Copy-pasting my code over (and learning how to install Newtonsoft) fixed the issue. Thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think compile all files into one is a good idea. If you want to have single file for downloading, you can package them into a self-extract zip format (winRAR, winzip or 7zip). Good luck~~