# Can I compile C# without having to include the reference .dlls in the console? (Linux)

Tags: c#, compilation

As part of my project I have two files that I need to compile, and they both depend on *System.Windows.Forms* and *System.Drawing*. When compiling I write:

`mcs engine.cs -r:System.Windows.Forms.dll,System.Drawing.dll`
`mcs main.cs -r:System.Windows.Forms.dll,System.Drawing.dll,engine.exe`

Right now this is a nuisance, but manageable, but I am afraid that it will get worse once I write more code. I am not using Visual Studio as I found it easier to just use Atom for everything.

I tried to search for Atom packages that can handle this automatically; bash scripts that compile with the references in the background, but I'm curious to know if there is a simpler way that I'm just not seeing.

Thanks.

Comment: You can create project file (csproj) and write all dependencies there. And then build the project just with simple `dotnet build`. By the way,  `System.Drawing & Windoes.Forms` are Windows-only and you may hit a problems trying to use them on Linux.

Comment: Isn't Atom being sunset this month and will not receive any further updates? I doubt it received much updates in recent years anyway.

Comment: @Serg Yeah, this is what I needed. Appreciate the help!

Comment: You might look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189549/embedding-dlls-in-a-compiled-executable