# Compile a C++/SDL with static library?

Tags: c++, dll, compilation, sdl, codeblocks

In Windows system I need to keep all those `.dll` files in the same as my `.exe`?
I wish I could just merge all files in one single `.exe`, there is any way how?

I am a Linux and Windows user, in Linux I only use the terminal, but in Windows I use [CodeBlocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dlls in windows are like .so in linux, they are made to be separate. If you want to merge a library, don't use dll, use static library instead (.lib)

Edit: If you are not writing the library (somebody already gave you the dll), take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336961/packing-an-exe-dll-into-one-executable-not-net)